# Getting a JPanel graphics color is always the same color

Tags: java, swing

I have a vertical color bar, it has 7 main colors all combined as a gradient. I then take that and paint it to a `JPanel` like this:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();

    Point2D start = new Point2D.Float(0, 0);
    Point2D end = new Point2D.Float(0, h);
    float[] dist = {
        0.02f,
        0.28f,
        0.42f,
        0.56f,
        0.70f,
        0.84f,
        1.0f
    };

    Color[] colors = {
        Color.red,
        Color.magenta,
        Color.blue,
        Color.cyan,
        Color.green,
        Color.yellow,
        Color.red
    };

    LinearGradientPaint p = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, dist, colors);

    g2d.setPaint(p);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
}
```

I then have have a click event in the same class, which looks like this:

```
public void mouseClick(MouseEvent evt){
    BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage)this.createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    int[] colors = new int[3];
    int x = evt.getX();
    int y = evt.getY();
    img.getRaster().getPixel(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), colors);
    ColorPickerDialog.sldColor = new Color(colors[0], colors[1], colors[2]);
    getParent().invalidate();
    getParent().repaint();
}
```

The line `img.getRaster().getPixel(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), colors);` always returns the RGB colors:

- 240
- 240
- 240

And I can click anywhere, on the Red, Yellow, Green, Cyan, etc. and I always get those RGB colors back. Why?

Comment: Is anything to be painted over the top of the gradient?  If not, paint it in a `BufferedImage` display the image in a label.  Add the mouse listener to the label & get the color directly back out of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

I replaced this line:

```
BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage)this.createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
```

With this:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
this.paint(g);
```

And now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

I think I see the problem.  The line

```
img.getRaster().getPixel(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), colors);
```

returns an int[] corresponding to the RGB colors.  The getPixel method takes in your array as
a parameter, but it returns its own array.  It never actually touches your array. what you want to do is this.

```
int[] colors = img.getRaster().getPixel(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), new int[3]);
```

that should store the return value of the method in your array instead of whatever it's default value is.

Comment: Nope, that didn't make any difference, it still contains the 3 same rgb colors.

Comment: So, I wrote `BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage)this.createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());` to a file, and it is a gray image.